# Find cameraParams Object in Matlab to compute disparity map

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, stereo-3d

I have downloaded the KITTY vision benchmark: [KITTY benchmark](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow.php?benchmark=stereo). 
The benchmark contains:

1. left images
2. right images
3. a folder calib containing txt files with four labels (P0 - P4) each with 12 values separated by space.
   Example of the first label:

> P0: 7.188560e+02 0.000000e+00 6.071928e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 7.188560e+02 1.852157e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
>   
>   I want to compute the disparity map for two left/right images as in this post:[Scene reconstruction in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-calibration-and-scene-reconstruction.html)

So I should use:

```
I1 = imread('leftImg.png');
I2 = imread('rightImg.png');


% Rectify the images.
[J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams);

disparityMap = disparity(rgb2gray(J1), rgb2gray(J2));
```

How can I obtain the ***steroParams*** parameter given the txt files from the calib folder? (I suppose that those files are for this task). Also, what are those four labels?